# Extract a same pattern file from various .tgz files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tar

I have a myarchive.tar file

```
myarchive.tar/a.tgz/folder1/folder2/folder3/abc.txt
             /b.tgz/folder1/folder2/folder3/ab.txt
             /c.tgz/folder1/folder2/folder3/c.txt
             /c.tgz/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/abcd.txt
```

How to extract only .txt files which has "a" in it's name, in one shell script command?
Please Help!

Comment: Do you have GNU `tar` on this machine (by tag it must be `unix`)?

Answer (score 0):

Can use `tar`'s `--wildcards` option. From the [tar man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

> --wildcards
>
> Use wildcards (default for exclusion).

So to extract all `.txt` files with `a` in the name from `myarchive.tar` the command can be:

```
tar xvf myarchive.tar --wildcards "*/*a*.txt"
```

Comment: I want to extract .txt files which has a in their names

Comment: `a` as the first letter or `a` anywhere in the file name?

Comment: a as in anywhere

Comment: `tar: */a*: Not found in archive`
I think this is because of .tgz files. How to overcome it

Comment: I would [gunzip it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499807/how-to-unzip-tgz-file-using-the-terminal), for instance by passing the `-z` option as well.